# Mastering UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiscrollview, wwdc

I would like to learn all the techniques related to UIScrollView about tiling and using it efficiently, I am particularly trying to figure out which videos to view from WWDC right from the beginning to the WWDC 11 movies. I am finding it difficult to segregate the videos which contain talks on UIScrollView. It would be grateful if someone who has already looked into it would share some pointers to start upon.

Also any quick guides or useful references are appreciated.

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WWDC 2010:
Session 104 - Designing Apps with Scroll Views

WWDC 2011 :
Session 104 - Advanced Scroll View Techniques
Session 115 - Scrolling, Swiping, Dragging